# Password confirmation not working - jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery-validate

I can't get why the same code isn't working. I'm using devise gem, so all input names are the same.

My password confirmation didn't work in other project.

Here is js code:

```
     $('.sign_up').validate({

    rules: {                    
        'user[password]': {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6
        },
        'user[password_confirmation]': {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            equalTo: "#user_password"
        }
    }
```

My html code:

```
      <label for="user_password">Password</label>
       <input id="user_password" type="password" size="30" name="user[password]">

        <label for="user_password_confirmation">Re-Type Password</label>
   <input id="user_password_confirmation" type="password" size="30" name="user[password_confirmation]">
```

Where is problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try don't use ''

```
$('.sign_up').validate({

rules: {                    
    user[password]: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 6
    },
    user[password_confirmation]: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 6,
        equalTo: "#user_password"
    }
}
```

and use the same word for input's id and name.